# Convert all png,jpeg,jpg to jpg and compress them using imagemagick

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

Im almost there with this code:

```
for PHOTO in /home/dvms/Desktop/projs/others/tests/gulp_test/src/images/*.{png,jpeg,jpg}
   do
       BASE=`basename $PHOTO`
    convert "$PHOTO" -quality 50% "/home/dvms/Desktop/projs/others/tests/gulp_test/src/imagesCompressed/$BASE.jpg"
   done
```

But the output files are appearing with their old file extension with a ".jpg" appended in the end, example: imageA.png.jpg .

How can solve this?

Comment: That's because you have this `$BASE.jpg` it should be `${BASE%%.*}.jpg`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen the answer of Parto worked but its also duplicating the images adding "imgOne-0.jpg", "imgTwo-1.jpg", etc...

Comment: I know it did just offering alternative syntax!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen The alternative syntax is good enough as an answer,too. Please post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
BASE=`basename $PHOTO`
```

With this one:

```
BASE=`basename $PHOTO | cut -d. -f1`
```

Then try again.

Comment: Its close, but it duplicates also the images adding "imgOne-0.jpg",  "imgTwo-1.jpg", etc...

Comment: I tryed now and it didn't duplicate the images, strange..

Comment: Please remember to quote all variables, as `BASE="$( basename "$PHOTO" | cut -d. -f1 )"` (note *two* sets of quotation marks). Without them, if any file name contains a space or certain special characters, you run the risk of data corruption. Also, the `cut` command won't work if a file name contains two or more dots; this needs to be changed; it can also, in certain cases, cause data being overwritten. The answer by @GeorgeUdosen provides a good option.

Answer (score 8):

Modify you code into this form:

```
for PHOTO in /home/dvms/Desktop/projs/others/tests/gulp_test/src/images/*.{png,jpeg,jpg}
   do
       BASE=$(basename $PHOTO)
    convert "$PHOTO" -quality 50% "/home/dvms/Desktop/projs/others/tests/gulp_test/src/imagesCompressed/${BASE%.*}.jpg"
   done
```

Rather than this `$BASE.jpg` use `${BASE%.*}` then add the extension.

Comment: You might want `"${BASE%.*}"` to use the *shortest* matching suffix pattern, so `my.long.filename.jpg` turns into `my.long.filename.jpg`, not `my.jpg`.  Also, worth checking that the output doesn't already exist, in case of collisions between different source suffixes.

Comment: Also worth checking if the output file is actually smaller than the input, otherwise just copy or link.  (Or check if the input jpg quality setting was below some threshold, but just comparing file size after an attempted recompression is easier and always works.)

Comment: Please add quotes: `BASE="$( basename "$PHOTO" )"`(two sets of quotes), in case the file name contains a space or certain other special characters.